# Why is my wordpress website displaying lines of html in place of performing the action it is programmed

Tags: html, wordpress, web, plugins

[image: Screen capture of website]

http://www.esafiber.com/

I am trying to get the website back in working order, however I have gotten stuck where it looks like the HTML bleeds through.

Any one seen this before? I am using WordPress and all of my themes and plugins are up to date.

Comment: Hello Sebastion,
Have you looked at the page in edit mode in the backend? Where exactly is the title defined on the page. If you could tell more about it, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a shortcode and it is not displayed properly.
You can check it via various way -

1 - Please check shortcode written in text area not visual if you use a text editor

2 - Please check theme or slider plugin is activated or not.

3 - Please check the theme or slider file if you are aware of customizing and check add_shortcode or do_shortcode written is in a proper way or not.